# Mouse and keyboard not working when upgraded from ubuntu 16.04 to ubuntu 17.04

Tags: upgrade, xorg, network-manager

Yesterday i upgraded my ubuntu os from ubuntu 16.04 LTS to ubuntu 17.04 and i find that my keyboard and mouse are not working i googled it and found that may be "xserver-xorg-input-all" is not installed i write the command "apt install xserver-xorg-input-all" but network is not connected. I clicked on enable networking in recovery mode but it also not connecting to my mobile hostspot. I tried "iwconfig" thing but it also didn't work for me. Then i tried "sudo service network-manager start" it also caused error saying timeout and all.
Please help..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you after upgrading. I tried every possible solution on askubuntu, but without success. As you specified, I wasn`t able to connect to the network to download the required packages. This is mainly due to the fact that is not recommended to upgrade to a non-LTS(not Long Term Support) version of Ubuntu. 
On the official website it is specified for both 17.04 and 17.10 that:

> The download of Ubuntu 17.10 is currently discouraged due to an issue
>   on certain Lenovo laptops. Once fixed this download will be enabled
>   again.

and also

> Mouse & Touchpad settings and behavior will not work right in the
>   Ubuntu desktop if `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` is installed. Some
>   desktop environments such as Unity require
>   `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`.

It seems like the problem is caused by a BIOS incompatibility.

You can read about the known bugs and the list of effected machines [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/ReleaseNotes?_ga=2.265762828.267869279.1514211917-1604797663.1514211917#Known_issues).